# AX-CRM Integration With purchse order

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, integration, ax

How to integrate CRM custom entity to AX Purchase order? Can we do it through connector?

Is there any non-programming solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box no programming solution.

My best advice is if you are looking for something easy use Scribe - but honestly, It would be a good idea to hire a developer that specializes in integration.